# TTY and/or ARF Response from Experian's API

Tags: php, xml, api

I'm trying to use the PHP Curl library to connect to Experian's API.

When I post a HTTPS request to Experian, I get an HTTP 200 OK response, but nothing more.  I am expecting a TTY or ARF response.  Do anyone have insight in what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a snippet of my code below for reference

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://stg1.experian.com/lookupServlet1?lookupServiceName=AccessPoint&lookupServiceVersion=1.0&serviceName=NetConnectDemo&serviceVersion=2.0&responseType=text/plain'); //not the actual site

//For Debugging 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);


//#2-Net Connect client receives ECALS response. This is the Net Connect URL.

$ecals_url = curl_exec($ch);

//#3-Net Connect client validates that the URL ends with “.experian.com”. If the URL is valid, the processing continues; otherwise, processing ends.

$host_name = parse_url( $ecals_url );
$host_name = explode(".", $host_name['host'] );
$host_name = $host_name[1].'.'.$host_name[2];

if( $host_name == "experian.com" )
{

    //#4-Net Connect client connects to Experian using URL returned from ECALS. 
    echo "step 4 - connect to secure connection<br>";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$ecals_url); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password"); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CERTINFO,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //times out after 10s 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    print_r ($result);
```

Comment: Can you share the final code? We're having this issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since I messed with our Experian Net Connect service but I believe you have to base64 encode the username:password value for their system to take it.